# Line integral - parametrized curve with composite polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

Find the definite integral for:
\begin{equation}
\int_C x^2y\,ds
,\quad
C:
\begin{cases}
x = \sin(t^3-4t) \\
y = \cos(3t^2)
\end{cases}
,\quad
t\in\left[1,2\right].
\end{equation}

Normally I'd substitute:
\begin{equation}
ds = \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}dt.
\end{equation}

But in this case the parameterized curve has polynomials inside the trigonometric function which makes it messy. I guess maybe the whole idea is to substitute somehow those polynomials?

Comment: Are you expected to get a closed form solution? Even Wolfram Alpha only gives a decimal approximation.

Comment: Yes, to the extent of my knowledge a closed form is desirable. I might be wrong though...